# Проблема с абсолютным позиционированием

Tags: php, html, css, position

В большом диве циклом вывожу товары.

В определенном месте этого дива есть картинка. Я ее позиционировал абсолютно, чтобы она именно в том месте была после вывода товаров в маленьких `div`.

Эти маленькие дивы с товарами лезут, понятное дело, под эту картинку абсолютно позиционированную. Может кто знает, как решить эту проблему. Чтобы изображение было на своём месте, а остальное пространство общего дива, как рассчитано, занимали маленькие блоки с товарами.

Comment: жаль бабы Ванги нету уже , показала бы вашу вёрстку ! Код надо вкладывать в сниппет

Comment: Верстка большая, надо выкладывать со стилями. Не поместится сюда. Дополню пояснение - две больших картинки находятся в разных углах общего дива, маленькие дивы с товарами должны выводиться зигзагом, обходя большие картинки как препятствия. Ух, таков дизайн, извините.

Comment: без примера не сказать что надо сделать -

Comment: #commonbackground{            /* Общий большой div для бэкграунда*/
    height: 1952px;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
   }

Comment: #picpromo{             /*Див с большим изображением "заголовок промо - товара"*/  
   width: 586px;
   height: 650px;  
   margin-top: 976px;
   margin-left: 585px;
   position: absolute;
  }

Comment: #divcategorydescript{        /* div для картинки с описанием категории*/
  width: 878px;
  height: 324px;
  float: left;
  }

Comment: .divpic{                       /*Дивы для блока с "изображением товара"*/
 background-color: #d1d3d4;
 width: 290px;
 height: 236px;
 font-family: 'Supermolot Light', Arial;
 font-size: 32px;
 line-height: 36px; 
 margin-left: 2px;
 margin-top: 2px;
 color: #ececed; 
 
 }

Comment: Я стили дивов с картинками и товаром в отдельных комментариях выложил. Не совсем понятно, но по другому не вмещаются.

Comment: отредактируйте вопрос , и всё что вы выложили в комментарии положите в сниппет , так можно быдет запустить пример и точно уже будет ясно о чём речь , но можно воспользоваться дополнительно http://codepen.io , http://jsfiddle.net и так далее но код сюда выкладывать обязательно

Comment: А где этот сниппет? Снова задать вопрос?

Comment: я прошу прощения что с задержкой отвечаю но  нажмите править и потом нажмите на иконку Лист бумаги загнутый и при наведении будет написано html/css/javascript и там увидите

Answer (score 1):

Верхний падинг задай на размер высоты этой картинки (которая позиционируется абсолютно)
и маленькие не будут под нее залезать

Comment: Дело в том, что вывод маленьких блоков с товаром идем зигзагом. Большая картинка является, как бы препятствием, которое они обходят.

Comment: выложи хоть скрин с этими картинками
как должно быть и как есть

Comment: Ничего если я из файлообменника ссылку выложу на файл? А его можно будет в браузере посмотреть все как есть.

Comment: https://dropmefiles.com/vn2dx вот ссылка на файл у него расширение только пхп убрать на html и там все красиво, как в дизайне

Comment: Нет, так ты никогда не спозиционируешь
тут нужно либо тоже ставить float left вместо position absolute 
и ставить в нужном месте блок
либо использовать какой нибудь плагин по типу Masonry

Comment: Да, я тоже такого мнения, Артем. Сегодня буду разговаривать с преподавателями, может это дизайнер не учел php.